# Laptop only boots Windows, doesn't find any bootable device

Tags: linux, windows, boot, linux-mint, zorin

I've got a really old laptop with no OS installed from a friend to set it up.
To get as much performance as possible out of it, I wanted to install Linux, specifically Mint Cinnamon. After the installation via USB was succesfull, I tried to boot it up, which didn't work. It said "Not Bootable Device". Just to test it, I installed Windows 10 and it booted fine. Now, a friend recommended Zorin OS which I installed now and it doesn't boot either.

Why's that? Is the computer somehow locked to Windows?

Comment: With out further information about the model that's hard to say. Depending on the model there might be a BIOS option to limit what can be booted.

Comment: @Seth It's an Acer Aspire V11 Touch.

Comment: Did you try to enable Legacy boot mode in the BIOS?

Comment: @harrymc I did just now and I'm reinstalling Zorin OS right now.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the problem was to enable Legacy boot mode in the BIOS.

With this setting, the installation Zorin OS went ahead.